# python win32print what does printer status 0 mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I am working with the win32print modul in python and want to know, if a printer is ready to print.

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041648/python-win32print-printer-status-confusion) and have an additional question. If I get the printer status 0, does it mean that the printer status does not fit to any available status?  Because the status 0 ist not listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc244854.aspx). If it is not what I assume, than I want to know what status 0 means.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The status 0 means "Unknown" its somewhere documented in the MS docs.