# python win32print printer status

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I've been using the win32print module for Python to delete print jobs older than 14 days. That worked quite well, but now I also wanted to get the status(online/offline/out of paper/...) of the printer and I'm facing the problem, that i always get the status code '0', no matter what status of the printer.
I also read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356617/python-win32print-what-does-printer-status-0-mean) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041648/python-win32print-printer-status-confusion). But i only learned, that the module should return a bitmask of all status that apply to the printer.

I have no clue what is causing the problem, that i always get "Unknown" as status.

Happens even in this simple code:

```
for printer in win32print.EnumPrinters(3):
    printer_handler = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer[2])
    printer_info = win32print.GetPrinter(printer_handler, 2)
    print(printer_info["Status"])
    win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handler)
```

Hope someone of you knows, what could possible cause this problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: Able to reproduce, but all my printers are offline / not connected. Nothing seems wrong with the code, it's just something the underlying *WinAPI* returns.