# Get Printer Status Code with win32print

Tags: python, printing, pywin32

I have read the documentation of `win32print` which indicates that `GetPrinter` is the method which is used to obtain the status of the printer. However, this method returns a complete tuple of data and I'm at a loss at to which element indicates the actual status. Any ideas?

```
(None, 'HP Deskjet F4400', '', 'USB001', 'HP Deskjet F4400 series Class Driver', '', '', None, '', 'winprint', 'RAW', '', None, 1600, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Posted an example of the returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `Level=2` into GetPrinter it should return a dict. Then you can examine the keys. So, you could do something like:

```
d = GetPrinter(yourPrinter, 2)
print(d.keys())
```

And look for 'status' in the keys.

> >
>   Returns a dictionary containing PRINTER_INFO_* data for level, or returns a tuple of PRINTER_INFO_2 data if no level is passed in.

I suggest using level 2 because that is the default. So it's actually the level being returned already (just as a tuple).

Comment: If two is the default, why isn't it represented as a dictionary without specifying?

Comment: Great question, I assume the developer(s) didn't want to remove "backwards compatibility" in that if anyone was using it and expecting a tuple, they didn't want to break that with an update.

Comment: Is there a status code for printers or print jobs which can be used to determine if a print job as been received by the printer?

Comment: It looks like 0x00000008 and 0x00000010. They are all listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc244854.aspx. Specifically see the section on "Job status" codes.

You could also check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041648/python-win32print-printer-status-confusion

Comment: Why does this throw an error in an infinite while loop?

Comment: `jobstate = win32print.GetJob(handle, identity, 2)['Status']`

Comment: `pywintypes.error: (87, 'SetJob', 'The parameter is incorrect.')`

Comment: Actually, [level 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be a better choice since that only returns the status - but unfortunately `win32print` claims "Level 6 is not supported"

Comment: ...level 2 is of course also documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, and there are the `win32print.PRINTER_STATUS_*` constants to check against

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the default level parameter for GetPrinter, it is returning a PRINTER_INFO_2 defined at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This is the C++ definition but it should match up with the 21 members in the response you provided.

```
typedef struct _PRINTER_INFO_2 {
LPTSTR               pServerName;
  LPTSTR               pPrinterName;
  LPTSTR               pShareName;
  LPTSTR               pPortName;
  LPTSTR               pDriverName;
  LPTSTR               pComment;
  LPTSTR               pLocation;
  LPDEVMODE            pDevMode;
  LPTSTR               pSepFile;
  LPTSTR               pPrintProcessor;
  LPTSTR               pDatatype;
  LPTSTR               pParameters;
  PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor;
  DWORD                Attributes;
  DWORD                Priority;
  DWORD                DefaultPriority;
  DWORD                StartTime;
  DWORD                UntilTime;
  DWORD                Status;
  DWORD                cJobs;
  DWORD                AveragePPM;
} PRINTER_INFO_2, *PPRINTER_INFO_2;
```